# Automate Xray Test Coverage/Traceability Matrix reports generation

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I've reviewed Xray docs available here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Version+2 but there are no endpoints for triggering generation of Test Coverage and Traceability Matrix based on specific criterias.

Is there an API available for automatic generation of Test Coverage/Traceability Matrix generation? Or do I need to do it manually via web browser?

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately and currently it is not possible to generate coverage or traceability reports from the API. I would suggest that you reach out [Xray team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2/user/login?destination=portal%2F2) and ask for an improvement request.